# Installing obs-backgroundremoval plugin on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, obs-studio

I already have obs-studio installed on My Jammy machine and its running well. Now, when I try to install [obs-backgroundremoval](https://github.com/royshil/obs-backgroundremoval) plugin I encounter a conflict in installation. When I try to install libobs-dev as a requirement I get a conflict error like the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
obs-studio : Conflicts: libobs0 but 27.2.3+dfsg1-1 is to be installed 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried to skip installing this package because I thought it might already have been installed with obs-studio. But, in a later stage when trying to build and install [this repository](https://github.com/royshil/obs-backgroundremoval) I get the following error which I think regards back to the package above. The error is:

```
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.34.1")
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:106 (find_package):
By not providing "Findlibobs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libobs", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libobs" with any
of the following names:

libobsConfig.cmake
libobs-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "libobs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"libobs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "libobs"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Is this a compatibility issue or am I wrong somewhere in the middle of the installation process?

Another question, is there a way to force packages to be installed even though there is a conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have resolved this already.

I found some useful installation instructions on one of the GitHub issues in that repository, see the [link for reference](https://github.com/royshil/obs-backgroundremoval/issues/34#issuecomment-942689271).

It is unclear how you have installed obs, but it might help to remove it and start clean (that helped in my case).

E.g. to remove the ppa version:

```
sudo apt remove obs-studio --auto-remove
```

Remove the linked ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio -r
```

Install from the Ubuntu repo:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install obs-studio
```

Then install the plugin using the pacstall package:

```
pacstall -I obs-backgroundremoval-git
```